# How do I enable Glippy/Parcelite's indicator applets?

Tags: 11.04, indicator, glippy

I have Glippy installed on my Natty machine. Everything was fine until a couple of days ago, when the indicator applet mysteriously disappeared. The same is the case with Parcelite. Does anyone else face this problem? If yes, is there a way we can get this applet to show on the top panel? If no, how do I troubleshoot this and get the applet back? Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the solution! I followed this [article](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-re-enable-notification-area.html) and 'enabled the systray for all applications'. Now I got glippy back on my systray.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ClipIt, a parcellite fork that supports ayatana indicators.

http://clipit.rspwn.com/ubuntu-ppa/

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's a nice alternative. But is there a way I can get Glippy to show up on the top panel?